# Openpyxl disable fill handle and cell drag and drop

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I would like to disable the fill handle and cell drag-and-drop feature for a particular column in an Excel sheet. However, after conducting extensive research, I have learned that it is not possible to disable this feature for just one column; it can only be disabled for the entire sheet. I am seeking suggestions on how to disable the drag option for a specific column or for the entire sheet.

I tried to add protection to a column using the code
`cell.protection = Protection(locked=True)`
but it did not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following code sample.

The code creates a workbook, adds some test cells and then sets and enables the protection.
For simplicity I am only working in the range from A1 to J50. If this suits you you can expand to the whole sheet (if that is necessary bearing in mind the way Openpyxl updates cells which may be a determining factor on using Openpyxl and/or applying to the whole sheet).

In this example I'm setting Column C as the column where drag and drop is disabled. 
So Column C keeps 'locked' enabled

[image]

and the other columns have it disabled.

[image]

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Protection

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()  # Create new workbook
ws = wb.active  # Default Sheet


### Write some data to the sheet for drag drop testing
ws['C4'].value = 'NoDrag1'
ws['C6'].value = 'NoDrag2'

ws['B5'].value = 'Drag1'
ws['D5'].value = 'Drag1'

### Remove protection from Columns A to J and up to row 50 leaving Column C untouched.
### This could be done in two loops, Columns A & B then D - J or disable across the 
### whole range and reapply to C which is the way I've done it here  
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=50, min_col=1, max_col=10):
    for cell in row:
        cell.protection = Protection(locked=False)

### Reset protection on for Column C back on
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=50, min_col=3, max_col=3):
    for cell in row:
        cell.protection = Protection(locked=True)

### Enable the protection on the Sheet
ws.protection.enable()

### Save the workbook
wb.save('protection.xlsx')
```

After the code is run and the workbook opened you will have a Sheet (called Sheet) that looks like the following;

[image]

- If you click on the cell 'B5' or 'D5' and attempt to drag it to another cell in the specified range A1:J50 other than Column C that should work.
- If you try to drag it into any cell in Column C you should get a protected cell error.
- If you try to drag the 'C4' or 'C6' (or any cell in the range C1 to C50) to any other cell on the sheet (in the specified range) you should get a protected cell error.

I believe this is your desired operation so try it and see.

If this is what you want, understand that applying this to the whole sheet means a lot of operations as Openpyxl works cell by cell so that would mean you having to loop through every cell in the Sheet, something like 17,178,820,608 cells. It's probably unlikely that you need to apply across the whole sheet so using the just the range that you will actually add data to would obviously take less time.
If you do need to apply across the whole sheet the you might want to consider using Xlwings or Win32com instead as these apps with use Excel and its operations  which can be applied across the whole sheet in one action which would be faster.